# Erro ao ler JSONObject dentro de um array

Tags: java, json

Tenho o seguinte JSON:

```js
{  
   "setor":6,
   "tipo":"S",
   "filial":1,
   "peso":0,
   "doca":1,
   "operacao":1,
   "usuario":1,
   "empresa":1,
   "movimento":23,
   "local":4,
   "ativos":[  
      "{\"ativo\":1,\"quantidade\":25}",
      "{\"ativo\":2,\"quantidade\":33}"
   ]
}
```

Os primeiros dados leio sem dificuldades, mas o Array não estou conseguindo. Estou fazendo assim:

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);

JSONArray c = jsonObj.getJSONArray("ativos");
for (int i = 0 ; i < c.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) c.get(i);  //aqui erro
    int ativo = obj.getInt("ativo");
    int quantidade = obj.getInt("quantidade");
}
```

Me retorna erro:

> Não é um Object

Answer (score 4):

O erro ocorre porque este array não tem objetos JSON, e sim strings. Tudo por causa das aspas:

```
"ativos":["{\"ativo\":1,\"quantidade\":25}", "{\"ativo\":2,\"quantidade\":33}"]
          ^                               ^  ^                               ^
```

Estas aspas delimitam uma string, e dentro de cada string tem um **texto** que corresponde a um objeto (mas não o objeto em si). Sendo assim, você deve ler os elementos como strings, e a partir de cada string criar um `JSONObject`:

```
JSONArray c = jsonObj.getJSONArray("ativos");
for (int i = 0; i < c.length(); i++) {
    // obter o elemento como String e criar um JSONObject
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(c.getString(i));
    int ativo = obj.getInt("ativo");
    int quantidade = obj.getInt("quantidade");
}
```

---

Claro que isto é uma "gambiarra" para contornar o problema de ter um JSON meio "estranho". O ideal seria corrigir o JSON na origem (onde ele é gerado), para que ele tenha um array de objetos (ou seja, sem estas aspas):

```
"ativos":[ {"ativo":1,"quantidade":25} , {"ativo":2,"quantidade":33} ]
          ^                           ^ ^                           ^
          não tem mais as aspas, agora são objetos (e não mais strings)
```

Aí sim você poderia ler desta maneira:

```
JSONArray c = jsonObj.getJSONArray("ativos");
for (int i = 0; i < c.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject obj = c.getJSONObject(i);
    int ativo = obj.getInt("ativo");
    int quantidade = obj.getInt("quantidade");
}
```